# My coding show an illegal start of expression

Tags: java

```
switch(course)                  
        {
            case "CS1001":
            case "CS1004":
            case "CS1005":
            case "CS1007":
            case "CS1008":
            case "CS1009":
                if(credit+3>20)
                {
                    System.out.println("You have exceed 20 credits, Please enter again!");
                    returnmenu:
                    }
                else
                {
                    credit+=3;
                    pay+=300;
                }
            break;
            case "CS1002":
            case "CS1006":
                if(credit+4>20)
                {
                    System.out.println("You have exceed 20 credits, Please enter again!");
                    returnmenu:
                }
            else
                {
                    credit+=4;
                    pay+=400;
                }
            break;
            case "CS1010":
                if(credit+2>20)
                {
                    System.out.println("You have exceed 20 credits, Please enter again!");
                    returnmenu:
                }
            else
                {
                    credit+=2;
                    pay+=200;
                }
            break;
```

Comment: all these labels are invalid `returnmenu:` syntax

Comment: What's your issue and your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return menu;
```

not

```
returnmenu:
```

Java reads this as a label but you don't have a statement after it.